# Can a module-info.java 'opens' statement include a package and all sub-packages?

Tags: java, spring, java-9, module-info

I have a `module-info.java` file that looks like -

```
module foo.microservice {
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.context;
    requires java.sql; // required for Spring Annotation based configuration :(

    opens foo.microservice.configuration to spring.core;
    opens foo.microservice.internal.services to spring.beans;
    opens foo.microservice.internal.controllers to spring.beans;

    exports foo.microservice.configuration;
    exports foo.microservice.controllers;
    exports foo.microservice.models;
    exports foo.microservice.services;
}
```

I'm hoping that it might be possible to allow Spring to access all internal packages without explicitly adding each one to the module-info.java.

Is there a way to have a more generic `opens` statement to allow all my internal packages (and sub-packages) to be accessible to `spring.beans`?

Comment: 'exports' and 'opens' have very different functionality within the module-info.java, so I didn't see these questions as duplicates of this one.

Comment: You can use `open module` to open all packages (internal or not) to all modules. I don't think there's any intermediate granularity.

Comment: @nullpointer Nicolai's answer explains why it isn't allowed for `exports` and states this reason doesn't apply for `opens`. So no, I don't think it answers why it isn't allowed for `opens`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently no, as the [JLS defines a module declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7) as a list of directives where each directive has the below syntax:

```
ModuleDirective:
     requires {RequiresModifier} ModuleName ;
     exports PackageName [to ModuleName {, ModuleName}] ;
     opens PackageName [to ModuleName {, ModuleName}] ;
     uses TypeName ;
     provides TypeName with TypeName {, TypeName} ;
```

The same syntax applies for both `exports` and `opens`: no wildcards are allowed in the package name. Maybe that could be improved in the future, but I think it would be a bad practice, similar to the bad practice of using such wildcards in import statements.

Comment: Plus one for the JLS link of the same.

Comment: The answer is correct, but I want to add that this does not have to be seen as unfortunate. Quite the opposite, I think that packages should always be explicitly and deliberately exported/opened. Furthermore, this would foster the misunderstanding packages with the same prefix are somehow related, which they aren't.

Answer (score 8):

You can use open module to open all packages (internal or not) to all modules. I don't think there's any intermediate granularity.

```
open module foo.microservice {
  requires spring.core;
  requires spring.beans;
  requires spring.context;
  requires java.sql; // required for Spring Annotation based configuration :(

  exports foo.microservice.configuration;
  exports foo.microservice.controllers;
  exports foo.microservice.models;
  exports foo.microservice.services;
}
```

(copied from Alexey Romanov's comment)